# Android save Bitmap with high quality or improve Bitmap quality

Tags: android, bitmap, image-capture

this is my code:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if (reqCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getData() == null) {
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)
                    data.getExtras().get("data");
            productImageImgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            productImageImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

            File pictureFile = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png");

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                        pictureFile);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                fos.close();
             //   String filePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        } else {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            productImageImgView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            productImageImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageUri = data.getData();


        }
    }
```

after saving image loses quality. i want to save Bitmap image with high quality or save image after improving quality.i need  advice about this topic

Comment: Try saving it as a PNG e.g. bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

Comment: i tried this but it is also loses quality.